# trim не выполняет свою функцию?

Tags: php, строки

Вот такая конструкция:

```
echo $alias."<br>";
trim($alias, '/');
echo $alias."<br>";
```

Выводит:

> `/user/steps/
> /user/steps/`

Что я делаю не так? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$alias = trim($alias, '/');
```

Функция возвращает значение. $alias передается не по ссылке.

Comment: Ёпта. Заработался. Пошел спать. Спасибо. (: